# How to export, then access exported methods in Lua

Tags: oop, lua

I have a file, display.lua in which I have code to load some resources.

```
----display.lua
Resources = {}

function Resources:new(rootdir)
  local newObj = {image = {}, audio = {}, root = ""}
  newObj.root = rootdir
  return setmetatable(newObj, self)
end

function Resources:getSpriteSheet(name)
    --- etc etc etc
end
```

and then I have a game variable I use to store gamestate, this is within another file game.lua.

```
---game.lua
require "display.lua"

function Game:new()
  local newObj = {mode = "", map = {}, player = {}, resources = {}}
  self.__index = self
  return setmetatable(newObj, self)
end

function Game:init()
  self.resources = Resources:new("/home/example/etc/game/")
  local spriteSheet = self.resources:getSpriteSheet("spritesheet.png")
end
```

I have access to the resources code via use of `require`. My issue is that within `Game:init()` I can't access `Resources:getSpriteSheet()`, the lua interpreter complains of "attempt to call method (getSpriteSheet) a nil value"

I assume here I would have to export the methods in Resources but I don't know how I'd go about doing this, as I'm quite new to Lua.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `return setmetatable(newObj, {__index = self})` instead of `return setmetatable(newObj, self)`.

Also, `require "display.lua"` should probably be `require "display"` and `game.lua` should have `Game = {}` somewhere at the top. With these changes your example works for me.